# Continuity of a Function with complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:**

Let $f$ be defined $$f(z)=\frac{{{\rm Re}(z^{2})}^2}{\left \| z^2 \right \|}$$ if $z\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.
Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Does any one have any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $|\Re z|\leqslant |z|$ so...?

Comment: this? 
[ tex ]\operatorname{Re}(z^{2})\le \left| z \right|^{2}[ /tex ]

[ tex ]\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z^{2})}{\left| z \right|^{2}}\le 0[ /tex ]

Comment: You need to use dollar signs. The point is to bound your function above by something that goes to $0$ as $z\to 0$.

Comment: \frac{Re(z^2)}{\left |z^2|\right}\leq 0 ?

Comment: You need to use dollar signs. But no, you want that to be $\leqslant 1$. Then your function is $\leq \Re(z^2)$.

Comment: $$ \frac{Re(z^2)^2}{\left |z^2|\right}\leq Re(z^2) ?  $$

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: sandwich theorem to prove that the limit is 0 right?

Comment: Sounds fine. ${}{}{}$